# Oracle error : ORA-00905: Missing keyword on ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, alter-table, ora-00905

I'm getting the error `ORA-00905: Missing keyword` with line:

```
ALTER TABLE Z_Paper_ObjTable ADD SCOPE FOR (institute) IN Z_Institute_ObjTable;
```

Table `Z_Paper_ObjTable` has an attribute `institute REF Z_Institute_ObjType`.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`alter table`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm) docs, the correct syntax would be:

```
ALTER TABLE Z_Paper_ObjTable ADD (SCOPE FOR (institute) IS Z_Institute_ObjTable);
```

Parens not optional, and `is` rather than `in`.